# How do I get the commun results in a for loop in a unknown array length PHP

Tags: php

I have a array of dates, I would like to get all values that are in all of them, thats my example:

```
$array = [
{"d1":["2016-01-04","2016-01-11","2016-01-18","2016-01-25","2016-02-01"]},
{"d2":["2016-01-05","2016-01-11","2016-01-19","2016-01-25","2015-12-12"]},
{"d3":["2016-01-05","2016-01-11","2016-01-25"]},
{"d4":["2016-01-04","2016-01-11","2016-01-25"]}
]
```

As result:

```
$result = ["2016-01-11", ,"2016-01-25"];
```

Comment: That's not all. That are just two.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a valid array to me...

Comment: @Andrew It's a valid JSON :). just decode it.

Comment: now the result doesn't make sense to me :(

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example (can be optimized, but it should work):

```
$array = json_decode('[
{"d1":["2016-01-04","2016-01-11","2016-01-18","2016-01-25","2016-02-01"]},
{"d2":["2016-01-05","2016-01-11","2016-01-19","2016-01-25","2015-12-12"]},
{"d3":["2016-01-05","2016-01-11","2016-01-25"]},
{"d4":["2016-01-04","2016-01-11","2016-01-25"]}
]');


$allArrays = array();

foreach ($array as $object) {
    foreach ($object as $datesArray) {
        array_push($allArrays, $datesArray);
    }
}

$sharedDates = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$allArrays);

var_dump($sharedDates);
```

Comment: Thanks Lucian ,I also found the array_intersect() Function,and it solved my problem.